# How to install Qpid Proton on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, qpid, qpid-proton

I want to use Qpid Proton on the raspberry pi 4 but I have trouble installing it.
Well, it seems I could install it and I can use the examples from the Apache website.

https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-proton-0.33.0/proton/python/docs/tutorial.html

However, the container's on_sendable callback does not seem to be executed.
After doing some research, it seems I need to add a topic exchange with the qpid-config, which is part of qpid-tools.

However, those are not available to install, both with pip or apt ...

Do you know how I can install Qpid-Tools on the raspberry pi?
Do I need to add a repository? And if so, where do I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doubtful that there exists a build of qpid-tools fir the ARM based distributions so the short answer is probably that you can't get those tools there.  The longer answer would be that you would need to likely build the qpid C++ binaries yourself on your Raspberry Pi using the included INSTALL instructions to try and reverse engineer the needed requirements and platform configuration that would allow it to build on ARM.

If you figure out the requirements you could feed that back to the Qpid community although I don't think there is much ongoing momentum for the Qpid C++ broker.

You can download the source bundle from the Qpid project site [here](https://qpid.apache.org/releases/qpid-cpp-1.39.0/).

Comment: I was afraid it would be something like that ... I found it easier to use rabbitMQ with Kombu.